# Is the structure of my HTML and CSS correct?

Tags: html, css

I researched online and completed all the things it said. I removed all unnecessary divs and etc. I wanted to know if there are any more suggestions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}
.navigation-bar {
width: 100%;
height: 53px; /
background-color: black;
}
.logo {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
height: 50px;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-top: 2px;

}
.navigation-bar> a {
float:right;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
margin-right: 25px;

height: 60px;
color: white;
line-height: 70px;
font-weight: bolder;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: sans-serif;
position: relative;
padding: 3px;
}

 .navigation-bar> a:hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
 top: 40px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -5px;

width: 0px;
height: 7px;
xxmargin: 0px auto;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;


}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navigation-bar">
  <img class="logo" src="C:\Users\sahan\Downloads\logo.png">
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">Us</a>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>

</nav>
```

Also Im getting the horizontal scrollbar. Im not supposed to use the overflow hidden property. How else can I stop the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is not suitable for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Does an HTML validator or CSS validator produce any errors or warnings about the code?  If so, address those.  If not, ask your instructor to clarify.

Comment: @sahrakmanswa: Based on the inconsistent use of indentation and the unclosed HTML elements, no.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? Correct by which means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improvements:

1. You should close your html and body tags

```
  </body>
</html>
```

2. If you want to focus on details, it would be nicer if the img and nav items were on the same tab
3. You shouldn't include your logo in your nav. The correct semantic order would be

```
<header>
  <img> // this could be in a div for branding
  <nav>
    <a>Menu item</a> // your nav should only contain your nav links
  </nav>
</header>
```

4. It would be better to place your styles in an external stylesheet, which you can link to in your head with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="filename.css" />
```

5. The `<head>` element *requires* a `<title>` tag within it.

I'd also like to add some general pointers. Choose an amount of spaces for your tabs and **be consistent**. So if you choose 2 spaces to be a tab, always use 2 spaces for every indentation, also within your CSS.

Extra: I see xxmargin in your CSS, that is not a thing.

Comment: I would highlight that an external stylesheet is *almost* a prerequisite and should be more heavily suggested; inline and `<head>` element styles are absolutely not the way to go.

Comment: @Martin I agree, but he says he's making this as an assignment so I guess this is schoolwork. I'm not sure if that topic comes at a later point, and so wanted to stay true to the assignment and give some general pointers without being overwhelming.

Answer (score 1):

In html structure, `nav` element should be set into `header` tag if it is going to be use as top navbar of your website. Then you set the `main` And finaly the `footer`

Answer (score 1):

why did you make your stylesheet in the same page than your html code ? My advice to you is to make two different page and in your html code you use

```
<link href="link to your css page" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

That would be more pratical when you will create several pages for a website.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Could you add more so it is useful to the OP?